# Dependency Analysis Error

Tags: iphone, code-signing, provisioning-profile, archiving

Submitted project to appstore got email about invalid binary. Fixed the error and now When trying to archive project getting **dependency analysis error**:

```
codesignerror: code signing is required for product type application in SDK iOS 5.1.
```

**How to fix this error?**